# How can I avoid the this version only supports 100 named groups error?

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to use a list of regexes (all of which mapped to one particular token) to search a line for that token, so  I tried to just concatenate all of the regexes with '|'s and use that to search, but the I ran into the following error:

```
AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups
```

How can I avoid the this version only supports 100 named groups error?

Comment: Could you give us an example of some of the regular expressions? There may be a better way to do what you're trying to do. In otherwords, the problem you think you have may not be the problem you actually have

Comment: I just took a deeper look at the particular expressions, and I see a lot of ...(...)(...)..., so I'm going to see if removing those inner () is an acceptable solution, and I'll update the question if it is not.

Comment: You should show us the regex you have a problem with. Else it is not possible to give advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you have over 100 named groups.  The solution is to make them un-named groups by replacing instances of (...) with (?:...).